# wrong java decimal and therefore wrong calculation

Tags: java, decimal

The output I got is like this:

```
number of bags ordered : 43 ($236.50)

discount : 5% ($11.83)

total cost : $224.68
```

that correct total cost should be `224.67` because `236.50 - 11.83 = 224.67`

the discount I got using `%.2f` shows `11.83` where the original value is `11.825`

```
total cost = bags ordered - discount

224.68 != 236.50 - 11.825 = 224.675
```

and just because I got a round up value and I don't want `224.68` but `224.67`.

how to ensure that it's 236.50-11.83=224.67 but not 236.50-11.825=224.675??

someone please help me with this ><

thankyou :)

Comment: .2f suggests floating point arithmetic which cannot be accurate.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use floating-point numbers for currency calculations -- use [decimal classes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)!

Comment: currently, my lesson haven cover till BigDecimal. i've got no idea using that in my coding D: any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider switching to the `BigDecimal` class. The [setScale(int newScale, RoundingMode roundingMode)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale%28int,%20java.math.RoundingMode%29) function can give you full control over the decimal places.

Comment: currently, my lesson haven cover till BigDecimal. i've got no idea using that in my coding D: any other ideas?

Comment: chances are that nobody will ever teach a class on `BigDecimal`... If you go through the page on the link or if you just google it you'll find lots of information and examples about it.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point arithmetic is evil for fixed decimals like one in currency. Just use integers and format the output so that you have 2 digits separated with a `.`, that will save you a lot of headaches.

If you really want to keep floats you should do some tricks with rounding and multiply/divide so that you actually do the same rounding done by printing, e.g.:

- 11.825 * 100 = 1182.5
- Math.round(1182.5) = 1183
- 1183 / 100 = 11.83

Comment: i able to make it using the second one :D but math.round() isn't in my syllabus yet=.= so do BigDecimal. so i dunno how to do it...

Answer (score 0):

Since you have to use no other library classes, you could still implement your own rounding method.

```
public static float round(float val) {
   return (val*100.0 + 0.5) / 100.0;
}
```

to round your values before you use them in subsequent operations.

Comment: However it's not accurate. Floating-point values don't actually have decimal places so trying to round or truncate to fixed numbers of decimal places is a chimera.